# Limited access to Web widget

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, widget

I have a website with a great base for a narrow category of data (such as astronomy). Customers interested in my content and they want me to be given them finished blocks (widgets) to paste into their site. API is difficult for them, they need just finished blocks with specific information.

My question is: Is it possible to display the widgets only on the sites of my customers and how to implement it technically? And if some unknown wise guy copied the widget code to his site, he could not see the widget content.

I understand HTTP_REFERER is not suitable, because it is easy to forge. And what are the technologies? I've heard about software tokens, and the ability to sign requests, but do not know if they are suitable for my situation and how to practically implement it. Please suggest?

If I start to work with my customers, then I shall include them into my database and can be stored there any info, associated with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished the task due to HTTP access control (CORS). Widget controller manages external requests via database settings:

- Customer ID
- Customer date range limit
- Customer domains which used for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header

So unknown customer couldn't render my widgets on their website even if they copied widget code.

Widget content loads dynamically into client iframe from external JS via ajax request. This ensures asynchronous data loading on customer website, and lets only authorized client with known domains to load widget content

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).